# eventfd_write() with 2nd argument=0 doesn't work?

Tags: c++, epoll

when eventfd_write() is called with 2nd argument=0, epoll_wait() never returns, but when the argument is set to 1.  epoll_wait() returns.

Here is how I reproduce:
./bug 0

It never returns.

./bug 1

It returns.

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int value = 0;
int efd = 0;

void* start(void* p) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": going to sleep for 5 sec" << std::endl;
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": going to call eventfd_write() with value=" << value << std::endl;
    const int rc = eventfd_write(efd, value);
    assert(0 == rc);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int epFD = epoll_create1(0);
    assert(-1 != epFD);

    efd = eventfd(0, 0);
    assert(-1 != efd);

    struct epoll_event event;
    event.data.fd = efd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN;
    epoll_ctl(epFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, efd, &event);

    value = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    const uint32_t nEvents = 2;
    struct epoll_event events[nEvents];

    pthread_t threadID;
    const int rc = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, &start, NULL);
    assert(0 == rc);

    sleep(1);

    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": going to wait for event" << std::endl;

    int n = epoll_wait(epFD, events, nEvents, -1);
    assert(n > 0);

    std::cout << "okay" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I compiled:

```
g++ -Wall bug.cpp -o bug -O3 -lpthread
```

Here is my glibc version:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
glibc-static-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
```

Here is my g++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:
Read the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/eventfd_write)

Longer answer:
"A write(2) call adds the 8-byte integer value supplied in its buffer to the counter"

"The file descriptor is readable (the select(2) readfds argument; the poll(2) POLLIN flag) if the counter has a value greater than 0."

So, writing 0 doesn't add anything to the counter, and a value of 0 means that the file descriptor being waited on is not ready.  Any non-zero value should work (except 0xffffffff which is reserved).

Comment: Yup. Imagine my surprise when the pointers I was casting to uint64_t and stuffing in the write call kept coming out broken. Could have saved me some debugging time if I'd read the docs before as opposed to after.

Comment: @dave thanks for cutting out the related paragraph.  I didn't expect that the user needs to sort of know the implementation -- "write(2) call adds the 8-byte integer value supplied in its buffer to the counter".  It is a very interesting implementation tho.  Really appreciate your help!